# View images as query results

Tags: database-recommendation, database-internals, dbms

I've done lots of research on the topic but I'm drawing a blank.  Are their any database engines that can return rendered images in the query response?

For example:

```
Select images from fruit where type = "apple";
```

Would return rows of the apple type as rendered images, png, jpg, etc.

Comment: Not quite sure what you’re asking. If you store a binary picture in a binary field in a row, you’ll be able to retrieve it. I think you’re wondering if something cleverer could happen? That’s a no

Comment: Databases can't display anything.  It is up to the Application on the Display Tier to render the Binary Larg OBject ( `BLOB` ) into an image.  Oh, most apps like to have the MIME Type sent to them also.

Comment: Just looking for a way to skip the app layer but still write SQL.  Something like what you can do with https://airtable.com/product but in a native SQL ide.  Kind of an edge case request.

Comment: You do realize what you linked is....an application

Comment: I linked it as an example of what is like to see in an ide.  And yes it is obviously an application.

Comment: (I ment to edit that post) IDEs are applications too. It is up to the app/IDE to know to display a `BLOB` as an image.  I believe "list of software" requests are "offtopic"  but it is possible.  https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-quick-tip-blobs-and-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not up to the database engine to render an image or provide any visualisations - that work is performed by the client application receiving the data returned by the database engine.

What you want to look for is an IDE or query tool that has in-built visualisation capabilities. SSMS does not do this natively for SQL Server, but there are plug-ins and alternative tools that can do this (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669952/see-images-in-ssms)).

For Oracle, SQL Developer is apparently capable of [rendering BLOBs in the IDE](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-quick-tip-blobs-and-images/). For other RDBMS you will need to research.

Comment: Mini Sql query might be my best bet.  Ultimately I think this will work for a prototype to see if it is worth doing a full app.